# "Winner winner chicken dinner"

Tags: phrases

What's the proper context to use this phrase? And who would usually say something like this? Sounds very childish.

Comment: Well it *is* childish. I've not actually heard that one, but I imagine it's much the same as *easy peasy lemon squeezy* (i.e. - invariably somewhat 'tongue-in-cheek').

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use this when someone won something, but it's quite colloquial. The "chicken dinner" part is just a nonsense rhyme, in the same class as "easy-peasy" (including its citrus and racist variations).

Answer (score 13):

This is usually heard in casinos. The croupier or dealer calls it out when someone wins (obviously). It comes (allegedly) from the days when a [chicken dinner](http://www.eduqna.com/Words-Wordplay/2713-words-wordplay-3.html) cost about as much as a minimum bet at one of the table games ($2). So winning such a bet was enough for a meal. The rhyme made it stick, of course.

Comment: From the days when "a chicken in every pot" meant wealth, I would guess that a chicken dinner meant an expensive dinner.

Comment: "Chicken dinner" could also be derived from the French term *poule*, meaning "hen" from which we obtain *pool*. And in casinos and gambling games there is often a "pool of money".  [French poule (“collective stakes in a game”) ..., which has been explained anecdotally as deriving from an old informal betting game in France - 'jeu de poule' - Game of Chicken (or Hen, literally)](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pool) in which *poule* became synonymous with the combined *money pot* claimed by the winner.

Comment: That's a fanciful explanation, but I'm more persuaded by the rhyming of *winner* and *dinner*.

Answer (score 1):

I'm quite sure I heard it in a movie, maybe "21" in the underground casino scenes. I don't think it's used in real life though.

Comment: I was just about to say this. :)

Comment: You mean "real casinos"?